# $x_t = A\sin(t) + B\cos(t)$ is deterministic

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, time-series

I've read that $$x_t = A\sin(t) + B\cos(t)$$ is a deterministic process, where $A,B \sim N(0,1)$ and independent, $t \in \mathbb N$.

How is it possible? At time $t$ we need to draw from two random variables!

Thanks!

Comment: It is not deterministic. I wonder if you read that something depending upon it is deterministic. For example $\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} x_t \, dt$ is deterministic.

Comment: @MichaelHardy It is said here at page 6 http://www.phdeconomics.sssup.it/documents/Lesson11.pdf

Comment: I see that at the bottom of page six it is mentioned that there is a technical definition of "deterministic" and that it does _not_ mean "not random". Obviously one would need to look at that definition.

Comment: $\ldots\,$and now I see that the answer to your question is on page 5 of the document to which you linked.

Comment: @MichaelHardy epic! I mean, the standard definition of deterministic is not random right? Anyway he just says that there is a way to see that you can get to that magic result, not how.

Comment: If, where you wrote "not how", you meant how you find $A$ and $B$ given the past, just suppose you have $$ \begin{align} & A\sin t_1 + B\cos t_1 = s_1 \\ & A\sin t_2 + B\cos t_2 = s_2 \end{align} $$ and you know the values of $t_1,t_2,s_1,s_2,$ so that you know the two sines and the two cosines. Then you have two equations in two variables $A$ and $B. \qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page 5 of this document to which you linked in comments contains the answer to your question.

"Deterministic" as defined there does not mean "not random".

It means it can be predicted by using the entire past.

I would interpret that as follows: the conditional probability distribution of the future of the process, given the past of the process, assigns probability $1$ to a single path.

Thus if you see the path up to a certain time, you then know the realized values of those two random variables $A$ and $B$ and so you know the whole future of the process.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are not random variables anymore then, I mean we draw from them only once?

Comment: If $A$ is a random variable and you seek conditional probabilities given the event that $A=a,$ then you're just working with the constant $a$ rather than the random variable $A.$ So in a sense every random variable is treated as not random when you condition on it.